# Sending Email in C# without authenticating

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I've tried this code to send Email without entering credentials :

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp server");

    mail.From = new MailAddress("sender email");
    mail.To.Add("receiver email");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;

    SmtpServer.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I get this server error:

> Sytem.Net.Mail.SmtpException 5.7.3 Requested action aborted;user not
>   authentificated

I've also tried:

```
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Still the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Are you sending email through GMail servers?

Comment: If you try to send via a server that requires authentication you must authenticate.  The solution is to do that, or use a server that does not require authentication.

Comment: Why set SmtpServer.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; if you want to send the mail anonymously? Does you smtp server allow anonymous login?

Comment: yes but i've also tested it with live servers and it was the same problem

Comment: This is the initialisation code I use for sending via gmail.             SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Host = Settings.SMTPServer,
                Port = Settings.SMTPPort,
                EnableSsl = Settings.SMTPUseSSL,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.SMTPUsername, Settings.SMTPPassword)

            };

Comment: Do i have to use the SMTP server of my email provider or i can use different servers